# Can I use @run_time in EXTERNAL_QUERY when using Scheduled Query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to use BigQuery which uses a Cloud SQL Postgres External Data Source. I'd like to keep it up to date every 15 minutes using a Scheduled Query so my dashboards can be up-to-date.

BigQuery appears to support parameters like **@run_time** which allow you to use BackFilling (it took me longer than 15 minutes to write this from the initial query that I want to append to, so I want to backfill).

I have a query like so in which I'd like to use that parameter to backfill minus 15 minutes:

```
MERGE INTO hd.users tgt
USING (
  SELECT * 
  FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("projects/my-project/locations/europe-west5/connections/hd",
  '''
    SELECT * FROM "User" WHERE "createdAt" >= @run_time - INTERVAL '15m'
  ''')
) src
ON src.id = tgt.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET id = src.id, createdAt = src.createdAt
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, createdAt) VALUES (id, createdAt);
```

Of course it works if I replace **@run_time** with **NOW()** but then I lose the ability to back fill. I don't see any reference in the documentation but then also nowhere does it state that it's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use `@run_time` in your external source as this parameter only exist in BigQuery. Also it is not the best practice to frequently query data from an external source since it is relatively slow compared to querying data from BigQuery.

What I suggest is to stream data (using [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/streaming-pipelines) or create a [Datafusion pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/overview#pipeline), etc) if your update frequency is around 15 minutes.

Comment: thanks. I'd like to use something like Dataflow but I'm using Redis Pub/Sub for realtime messaging and prefer it, due to having pattern matching support that's unavailable with Google Pub/Sub. I'd have to publish to 2x places to get Dataflow... I'll have to think about it